# CodeIgniter - Directory Traversal - sanitize_filename()

Tags: security, codeigniter, directory, traversal, sanitize

If I use the CodeIgniter File Upload Class and rename the image being uploaded using:

`$config['file_name']`

do I still have to use

`$this->security->sanitize_filename()`

on the image being uploaded by user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set `$config['encrypt_name'];` will automatically rename users uploaded file or image for more information check user guide of File uploading library

[File Upload Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Thank you for response.

I need to save the image as the person's USERNAME with .jpg or.png at the end.

I will definitely try to implement $config['encrypt_name']; in the future, but if I keep it the way it is now using:

$config['file_name'];

Will I be ok from directory traversal?

Comment: Also, I am confused about directory traversal and maybe someone can clear this up for me.

Does the danger from directory traversal come from PROCESSING an unsafe filename OR does the danger come from STORING an unsafe filename?

For example: if someone were to try and upload an image with an unsafe filename, and you simply renamed it, is everything ok? Or do you have to sanitize the filename BEFORE you rename it or do any kind of processing?

Comment: as i search out this directory traversal problem is solved since CI 1.7.3 well i will also have look on this matter something really serious in case if you have windows server.